# Can't get SSL certificate from LDAPS server

Tags: active-directory, ssl, ssl-certificate, ldap, openssl

I'm trying to retrieve the public SSL certificate from my organization's LDAPS server.  I'm following the instructions [here](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Obtain%20a%20Certificate%20from%20Server), which recommend I run the following `openssl` command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect mydomain.local:636
```

This command establishes a connection, but seems to indicate there is no certificate found:

```
CONNECTED(000001C0)
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 308 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1535471188
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
write:errno=10054
```

Does this mean that my organization is using LDAP instead of LDAPS on port 636?  Is there another way to get the SSL certificate being used by my organization for LDAPS?

Comment: You may want to try a different tool such as NMap with the ssl-cert script with the -vv switch, it extracts the full certificate.  https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-cert.html . Also try an fqdn of a domain controller instead of the domain name.

Comment: `New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)` means it is not doing TLS at all...

Answer (score 1):

It likely means your organization either hasn't installed a certificate on the domain controller you connected to or the cert it has is invalid/expired. Unless they remediate that, LDAP won't be listening on 636 (or 3269). It will only be listening on 389 (and 3268) for non encrypted LDAP.